# Period End - Variance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working with a database that has a table with all the payments made every period end. I have to work out the variance of this months payment compared to the previous period end. I have wrote a SQL query but it looks dirty, and doesn't look the best way to do it.

```
((SELECT payment FROM paytable py1 WHERE py1.pay_id = pn.pay_id  AND period_id = '201310') 
  - 
((SELECT payment FROM paytable py2 WHERE py2.pay_id = pn.pay_id AND (period_id = '201310' -   1)))) as 'Payment Variance',
```

Have many of these calculations to make. What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: Shame you are using 2008. If you would be able to shift to 2012, there's a new `LAG` function that would easily solve your issue:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help? Basically join the same table to itself on a period-1.

```
SELECT py1.period_id, py1.payment - py2.payment as 'Payment Variance'
 FROM paytable py1 
 INNER JOIN paytable py2
        ON  py2.pay_id = py1.pay_id
        AND py2.period_id = CAST(CAST(py1.period_id as int) -1 as varchar(10))
 WHERE  py1.pay_id = pn.pay_id
```

Comment: Which way is best? As I would have to have multiple inner joins for this query.

Comment: You haven't shown the full query (i.e. where "pn" alias table is) so can't help much further. What I have shown will get every period_id and give you the variance between n and n-1 (where n is your period_id).

Comment: Thank you, after trying it out, it worked as i expected. Thank you!